# RN Google Signin native module is not correctly linked

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am really stuck with this error (RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked...),

I tried tried to follow suggestions here https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin/issues/771#issue-514898758 but they were not helpful

I have have followed all right procedures but still fail. I have tried it for three days!!
Please someone should help with a clear solution...

I use `RN^0.61.2` and latest `@react-native-community/google-signin` version

Comment: can you share details on your `env`? did you use `npm` or `yarn`? if so, what versions do you have?

Comment: Mubaraka Mubahood, did you finally manage to solve the problem because i have the same problem? Thanks

Comment: This setup needs to be followed to remove this error: https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/master/docs/android-guide.md